# Code Signed .exe on unc path

Tags: c#, windows, networking, truststore

I have been doing a lot of research on code signing and the windows security prompt.  I have a code signing certificate from comodo and everything appears to work great for the most part.

1) If all the files are on my local disk - works fine
2) If the files are on a UNC path and the server is on the same domain as my local machine - gravy

However, If the files are on a UNC path and its on another domain or no domain I get a nasty dialog "We can't verify who created this file..."  Even though the file properties dialog shows the file is properly signed with no errors on the certificate.

The command I am using to sign my files

```
signtool.exe sign /v /ph /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161 /ac "<comodo key>" /f "<my key>" /p <mypass> <file>
```

am I missing something or is this just the way it is?

Comment: Perhaps `signtool` decides that it cannot trust the file server if it is off domain

Comment: unc paths that are off-domain are automatically untrusted which is what pops up the dialog. It is a security measure. You can work around it, but it's there to prevent you from running applications from actual unknown sources over UNC.